# Javascript Inheritance and this

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a namespace called ns and ns has to functions on it:

```
ns = {};
ns.Foo = function(message, fn){
    this.message = message;
    fn.call(this);
};
ns.bar = function() {
    alert('Hello, world!');
};
```

And I call it like this:

```
var foo = new Foo('My Message', function() {
    bar();
});
```

I get an error saying bar() is undefined. But if I call it this way:

```
var foo = new Foo('My Message', function() {
    this.bar();
});
```

It works. Is there a way to structure my JavaScript so I can just call bar() without the this?

Thanks!

Comment: No. Any attempt to do this is a dirty hack.

Comment: Deleted my answer because I didn't notice you were calling `Foo` as a constructor. Using `this.bar()` does not work as you stated because `this` in `Foo`, and therefore the callback, is not `ns`, but rather the new object being created by the constructor. http://jsbin.com/otegos/edit#javascript,live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. JavaScript is not Java. You need to specify object whose method you're calling.

Comment: Unless the parent object is window? Just wondering why it works for objects defined in the global scope.

Comment: @Paul because window is special & ugly. Your accessing global objects. The fact that `window` is also the global container that contains all global objects by name is a seperate thing

Comment: Javascript `!==` Java??? What have you been smoking? They are essentially exactly the same, except JS is interpreted. And JS has no strong typing. And JS has no classes. And ...

Comment: `window` is not part of JS as such. It's part of most commonly used implementation (i.e. built-in browser JS) and can be thought of as part of a 'framework' of sorts, that make programmer's life a bit easier (or more miserable depending on occasion)

Comment: @trinithis: ... and programming in JavaScript is actually fun? ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing might be solved with closures.

JavaScript has no native concept of a namespace. There are namespace patterns people have used where they simply define a collection of tools inside a single object so that they don't pollute the global scope.

When you use "apply" or "call" the only difference is you've re-bound what "this" refers to as the function executes. You do not change it's parent scope.

Since these pseudo-namespaces are really just normal objects (not scopes) you cannot call its members without qualifying which object they belong to.

If you used a closure (which is a scope) instead of an object pseudo-namespace you could call members of the closure implicitly in functions that are defined inside the closure. For example:

```
var ns = {};
(function() {

    var Foo = ns.Foo = function(message, fn){
        this.message = message;
        fn.call(this);
    };

    var bar = ns.bar = function() {
        alert('Hello, world!');
    };

    var doStuff = ns.doStuff = function() {
        var myFoo = new Foo('My Message', function() {

            // "this" is unnecessary because bar is defined 
            // in this scope's closure.
            bar();
        });
    };

})();

var foo = new ns.Foo('My Message', function() {

    // Sill need "this" because bar is not defined in the scope
    // that this anonymous function is being defined in.
    this.bar();
});
```

You might also be able to use the "with" keyword, which explicitly modifies scope.

```
var foo = new ns.Foo('My Message', function() {
    with (this) {
        bar();
    }
});
```

Be warned though, the "with" keyword is generally frowned upon because it makes debugging difficult.